# Too long delays when using workmanager with notifications

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

My problem is that I received a notification 1 day later... And that doesn't suit me. Is this the normal behaviour? If so, do you have any alternatives for me to receive the notification at the right time?

I have created a notification module that uses Workmanager and you can find it [here](https://github.com/zackdu35/notification_module_work_manager/)

Each time I schedule a new notification, I do a

```java
OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker::class.java).setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

where my `delay` is only 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be surprised that exact notification won't work, reason being is that WorkManager isn't designed for this.

Please read "Choosing the right solution for your work" at https://developer.android.com/guide/background/#choosing_the_right_solution_for_your_work

As you can see, WorkManager is not the right solution for exact notifications

`setInitialDelay` only creates an initial delay. It doesn't guarantee immediate execution after the delay

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand much better now. However, I had seen in the WorkManager doc that it was based on : - JobScheduler on devices with API 23+
- Uses a combination of BroadcastReceiver + AlarmManager on devices with API 14-22
That's why I was a little confused...

Comment: Thanks I've removed the link